# Turtulebot not showing in custom world

Tags: ros

I  made a map.world file and placed it under

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds
```

and ran

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch world_file:=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/map.world
```

as mentioned [here](https://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/03/6/)

I see the map but I don't see turtlebot. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to *Robotics*, sevebebe. Your question doesn't include any supporting information, so it's hard to tell what you have and what you've done. From the [bringup guide](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_gazebo/Tutorials/indigo/Gazebo%20Bringup%20Guide):

> In this tutorial, we will bring up the turtlebot in the Gazebo simulator. This tutorial assumes you have completed [TurtleBot Installation](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation).

Did you install the turtlebot? What do you get if you run the following?

```
$ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```